# The name for an assumption made for the sake of contradiction - the marked assumption?

Tags: proof-writing, terminology, article-writing

*What is the name (or adjective) for an assumption made for the sake of contradiction?*

To be clear, I'm in search of an expression in the form "a(n) $\underline{\quad \quad \quad \quad}$ assumption".

I liked the suggestion "the marked assumption", found in the comments to this mathoverflow question asked by Me: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362848/the-name-for-an-assumption-made-for-the-sake-of-contradiction. Unlike Willie Wong's suggestion the "contradictive assumption", the "marked assumption" only partially suggests the nature of the expression. This is hard to fix unless the expression is made standard.

An advantage of the "marked assumption" is that it can serve double-duty: Even in cases where the truth of the assumption is unknown, the expression is still relevant. This is particularly notable in the study of the Riemann Hypothesis where the Riemann Hypothesis is occasionally assumed and consequences derived therefrom. If the marked assumption holds, then all we have done is discover consistent structure. If the marked assumption fails, then our presumptive work can just be seen as a search for a contradiction.

Comment: I understand why you asked here, but it also might be useful to ask on https://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think there is a widely known or used name.  You can use "marked assumption" as long as you mark the assumption (say, put it in bold or put an asterisk after it).  A more clear description would be to put the asterisk and then call it "Assumption *"; or put a number and refer to it as "Assumption 5." Another approach is to write "assume (for the sake of contradiction) that [blah blah]." Then any contradiction you reach afterwards will complete your proof.